# What does internal/ external merge mean in Git?

Tags: git, merge

In the git, the two branches are merged, but sometimes it is the internal merge and sometimes it is the external merge. I am not familiar with Git. What do these two terms mean? And what's the usage scenario of them?

In a program, the author wanted to figure out what kind of the merge is and he defined as follows.

```
'ExtMerge': re.compile(r'^ +Merge( (branch|branches|tag|tags) .* of)? ([^ ]+:[^ ]+)( into .*)?\n$'),
'IntMerge': re.compile(r'^ +(Merge|Pull) .* into .*$'),
'IntMerge2': re.compile(r"^ +Merge branch(es)? '.*$")
```

Comment: The terms "internal" and "external" are *not* usually used with Git. They are more common with Mercurial. Where did you see these terms?

Comment: I think it's better to add the snippet to the question as code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those regular expressions are obviously designed to match the default messages that `git merge` formats for you, or in one (the first) case, that `git pull` instructs `git merge` to format for you:

```
^ +
```

This looks for one or more spaces at the start of a line.

```
Merge
```

This of course matches the literal word "Merge".

```
( (branch|branches|tag|tags) .* of)?
```

This matches an optional  `branch anything of` (with leading space).  This looks a lot like Python code; if so, the parentheses imply both grouping, which is necessary for the `?` to make the entire sequence optional, and the ability to retrieve the matched strings.

```
 ([^ ]+:[^ ]+)( into .*)?\n$
```

This last part would capture some word that contains one colon but no white space that consists of at least one character on either side of the colon, followed by an optional  `input anything`, followed by a literal newline, followed by a blank line or end-of-string (the `\n$` sequence is a little tricky and perhaps redundant).

Hence:

```
 Merge branch 'foo' of ssh://example.com into bar
```

(note the leading space before the `M` in merge) is likely to match here.  This is the default message that `git pull ssh://example.com foo` would generate if you were on branch `bar` when you ran it.  This is also likely to match:

```
 Merge branch 'foo' of ssh://example.com
```

This is the default message that `git pull ssh://example.com foo` would generate if you were on branch `master`.

The second regular expression:

```
^ +(Merge|Pull) .* into .*$
```

is fairly similar; it matches anything starting with blanks and the literal word `Merge` or `Pull` followed by a space followed by anything followed by `into` (including both space) followed by anything.  The `$` at the end is redundant.  Note that this regular expression *also* matches:

```
 Merge branch 'foo' of ssh://example.com into bar
```

Hence, if the labels `ExtMerge` and `IntMerge` are meant to be meaningful, this particular `pull`-generated message indicates that the merge is both "internal" *and* "external".

The last regular expression is:

```
^ +Merge branch(es)? '.*$
```

This, as before, matches leading spaces (requiring at least one), the literal words `Merge branch` followed by an optional `es` followed by a space and a single quote `'` and then anything up through the end of a line.  The final `$` is redundant, as in the second case, since `.*` will consume everything up to the end of the line anyway.

This matches the default merge message that `git merge` generates.  However, it also matches, for instance, the very same:

```
 Merge branch 'foo' of ssh://example.com into bar
```

that we saw at the beginning.  So apparently this is simultaneously an *external* merge and two *different* kinds of *internal* merge, in the nomenclature of whatever source code you are using.

All of these *default* merge messages are *editable* and it's possible for whoever is running `git merge`—perhaps via `git pull` or perhaps not—could change them.  So it's impossible to say what whoever wrote these regular expressions had in mind.  Perhaps you could ask that person directly.